# Flutter Provider - Circular Dependencies using ProxyProvider`

Tags: flutter, dart, circular-dependency, flutter-provider

I have the following services:

1. `SecuredStorageService()`
2. `ApiService({this.authService})`
3. `AuthService({this.securedStorageService, this.apiService})`
4. `RegisterService({this.apiService, this.securedStorageService})`

Which lead me to write:

```
providers: [
  Provider<SecuredStorageService>.value(value: SecuredStorageService()),
  ProxyProvider<AuthService, ApiService>(
    builder: (_, auth, __) => ApiService(authService: auth),
  ),
  ProxyProvider2<ApiService, SecuredStorageService, RegisterService>(
    builder: (_, api, storage, __) => RegisterService(apiService: api, securedStorageService: storage),
  ),
  ProxyProvider2<ApiService, SecuredStorageService, AuthService>(
    builder: (_, api, storage, __) => AuthService(apiService: api, securedStorageService: storage),
  ),
],
```

I can tell until this point that it already looks messy. But that's not the case. When I run the app, I get the following error:

[image]

So what I do? I add before all of the `ProxyProvider`s a `Provider<AuthService>`. But then, the AuthService is being constructed twice! Which loses the whole point of being a singular instance (or isn't it?).

My main goal is to make a sort-of dependency injection just like in Angular or Laravel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ProxyProvider` and widgets in general fights against circular dependencies, as it's usually a sign of "spaghetti code" ([see more](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references))

As such, using `ProxyProvider` you won't be able to make a circular dependency graph.

If that's truly what you want, consider using `Provider.value` and manually handling your dependencies.